# Meaning of コース in a football match

Tags: meaning

Referring to a moment in Japan's  game against Spain in the world cup where the ball seemed like it might have gone over the line:

> 堂安選手は「自分が好きなコースだったので、絶対に決めると思って蹴りました」と話しました。
> Douan said "it was a ?? I liked, so I thought I will absolutely go for it, and kicked [the ball]".

I have two problems here. I'm not at all sure how to translate 決める in this case. "Go for it" seemed to work.

My main confusion though is コース. I don't know what this means. My only guess is that it refers to the 'course' from the player to the goal i.e. he had a good angle to shoot. Am I even close?

Comment: This is NHK News Easy, right? It appears, looking at the regular article, that what he actually said was 「あそこは俺のコースなので絶対にシュートを打ってやると決めていた。思いきり打つことができた」. They changed it quite a lot in simplifying it. The regular article also makes it clear that this is about the game-tying goal, not the controversial goal that had to be reviewed for potentially crossing the line.

Comment: @Leebo That's right. I guess that clears up the 決める part. But I'm afraid あそこは俺のコースだ is equally meaningless to me.

Comment: The thing is, the two uses of 決める are pretty different. I would have said he was using 決める to mean "to score" in the Easy version. In the regular version, it's not the "score a goal" 決める, just the normal "make a decision" 決める.

Comment: I wonder how an English player would have said what he said. Their favorite what?

Comment: @aguijonazo Not a fan of football at all so I don't really know. I would have thought "favourite shot" would be the closest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to the the trajectory the ball follows from the point where it is kicked through a particular area of the goalmouth. I think this usage of コース started in baseball in which the Japanese-English terms インコース and アウトコース refer to what Americans would call "inside pitch" and "outside pitch", respectively.

Note that Doan is the player who scored the first goal for Japan, not the second. He saw the trajectory the ball would follow before he took the shot.